# Does a polynomial mapping, which acts as a deck transformation for two 'independent' polynomials, have to be the identity?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f=\left(\begin{array}{c}
f^1  \\
f^2 
\end{array} \right)\colon \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ be a polynomial mapping.

Let $p,q \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be polynomials.

Denote $\nabla p = (p_x, p_y)$, 
$f^*(p):=p \circ f = p(f^1,f^2)$.

**Question:** Assuming $f^*$ preserves $p$ and $q$, i.e. assuming:

$p \circ f = p$,

$q \circ f = q$,

and assuming $\nabla p$ and $\nabla q$ are linearly independent at every point of $\mathbb{C}^2$, (viewed as vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$),
does it follow that $f$ must be the identity ?

**My thoughts:** Using the chain rule on $p \circ f = p$, one gets

$D_f \cdot f^*(\nabla p) = \nabla p$,

where $D_f := \left( \begin{array}{cc}
f^1_x & f^2_x \\
f^1_y & f^2_y 
\end{array}\right)$, and where $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication.
The same holds, of course, for $\nabla q$. The vectors $\nabla p, \nabla q$ form a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$ at every point. Thus, at every point, $D_f \cdot f^*$ act as the identity.

Comment: No. Your reasoning is just as wrong as in the one-dimensional case. $p'(f(x)) * f'(x) = p'(x)$ and $p'(x) \neq 0$ doesn't imply that $f'(x) = 1$.

Comment: If you fix $(x,y)$ and consider as a function of $t\in {\Bbb C}$:
$$ p\circ f(tx,ty)=p(tx,ty)$$
then they should have the same degree in $t$. I suspect you may use that in a constructive way.